# D&F Definition of rank on modules - need explanation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, definition

In Dummit & Foote's *Abstract Algebra*, pg 460, Chap 12, they defined:

> For any integral domain $R$ the *rank* of an $R$-module $M$ is the maximum number of $R$-linearly independent elements of $M$.

Sorry if these are obvious:

**(i)** If the maximum number is not finite does this mean we define the rank as: *the cardinality of **a** maximal $R$-linearly independent set.*

**(ia)** But then we would have to show all maximal $R$-linearly independent set have same cardinality?

**(ib)** How do we know such a maximal $R$-linearly independent set of elements in $M$ exists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**(i)** is the correct definition.

**(ia)** follows from the fact, that if $U \subset M$ is a maximal $R$-linearly independent subset, then $U$ is a basis of $M \otimes K$, where $K$ is the fraction field of $R$. Thus we get the result from the well known result in linear algebra. This also implies that the rank is nothing but $\dim_K M \otimes K$. In many sources you will find this as a definition.

**(ib)** is a consequence of Zorn's Lemma. This is essentially the same proof as the proof that any vector space admits a basis.